# Using JavaScript / Regex to replace >> (double greater than signs)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need " >> " to be replaced by "/"
String :  Test 2 >> Cat >> Cat2
Would become: Test 2/Cat/Cat2

Please know that I spent a ton of time reading all stack overflow and visiting fiddles but I can not get this right.
I used online Regex tools, https://regex101.com/ and  https://regexr.com/ and they confirmed RegEx was fine.
Each of these has tested positive in Regex testing tools but I'm still not getting results I expect.
I can not share code but here is a demonstration.

```
<span id="catidX"> Test 2 >> Cat >> Cat2 >> Cat4 || //// Cat /// Cat2 // Cat4 // CCat / CCat2 // CCat3 ///</span>
<script>

   var str = document.getElementById("catidX").innerHTML; 
    //var resA = str.replace(/[>]{2,}/g, "/");    - Attempt
    //var resA = str.replace([>]{2,}/g, "/");     - Attenmpt
    //var resA = str.replae(/>{2,}/g, "/");     - Attenmpt
    var resA = str.replace(/>>|>{2,}/g, "/");     
    var resB = resA.replace(/\/\//g, "/");
    document.getElementById("catidX").innerHTML = resB;
</script>
```

This code above produces the results

```
Test 2 >> Cat >> Cat2 >> Cat4 >> Detail || -- Cat -/ Cat2 - Cat4 - || CCat / CCat2 - CCat3 -/
```

I was just passing it through to replace to see results in both parts of the string.

UPDATE

- As per one of the helpful comments from a user - I added console.log(resB) to see what was output... which is not > but html for > -  &gt

[image: GT hTML]

With that info - I edited that line but still no success

```
var resA = str.replace(/&gt;{2,}/g,"/");
```

Comment: Print out `str` to see what is its content.

Comment: (use `console.log`)

Comment: If you are replacing only `>>`, does it need to use RegEx? You can simply use `str.split('>>').map(text => text.trim()).join('/')` and solve the problem, unless you have other things you need to do using RegEx.

Comment: I don't understand how you get this result from you code, Why do you repace multiple `>` with `--` and `//` with `--`? This doesn't fit the title (and the content) of your question. Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63351398/edit) and add your exact input string and expected result.

Comment: @toto - when it wasn't working I thought maybe something odd was going on with / so I temporarily swapped it with - and -- just to help visually debug. Question edited

Comment: @user202729 - that was a good suggestion - console.log is outputting the follow. Should I add to my question ?
Test 2 &gt;&gt; Cat &gt;&gt; Cat2 &gt;&gt; Cat4 || - Cat - Cat2 - Cat4 - CCat - CCat2 - CCat3

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I did accept the answer by @Toto as it specifically addressed.
The question included a scenario for >> and //  - the // only being an extra test.
The answer accepted not only addressed those scenarios but fixed both problems once  console.log determined >> was ACTUALLY &gt;&gt;
Handling the >> and &gt; is nice.
Final Regex used was replace(/(?:>|&gt;){2,}/g, '/');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = 'Test 2 &gt;&gt; Cat >> Cat2 &gt;> Cat4 || //// Cat /// Cat2 // Cat4 // CCat / CCat2 // CCat3 ///';
res = str.replace(/(?:>|&gt;){2,}|\/\/+/g, '/');
console.log(res);
```

- `(?:>|&gt;){2,}` is a non capture group that matches 2 or more "greater than" `>` or html entity `&gt;`
- `\/\/+` matches 2 or more slashes

Comment: This does work and addresses my example. 
Interestingly enough - I didn't need both statements to deal with &gt; and // but was using that as an example of two scenarios in trying to understand why the >> was not working.
Implementing your solution and then modifying it to only address what I need worked in all scenarios @toto - thank you!

Comment: @user2812171: You're welcome, glad it helps; Your attempt doesn't work because `&gt;{2,}` matches `&gt` followed by 2 or more `;` (i.e. `&gt;;;;;`) , it doesn't match a single `;`

Comment: This comment is why I love StackOverflow. This was very helpful so I can apply this understanding. I thought all my RegEx checked out in online regex tools. Is it appropriate to ask you to look at a new separate question I asked when I use your answer in a larger function. Stack question is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406932/javascript-stringed-replace-regex-function-replaces-characters-gtgt-in-pa]

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var str = "Test 2 >> Cat >> Cat2 >> Cat4"
str.replace(/>>/gi, "/");

result : "Test 2 / Cat / Cat2 / Cat4"
```

Comment: Just some lines of code without any explanation is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
/([>]{2})(?=[\s])+/g
```

Comment: The trailing `+` is superfluous and not really well-defined. `\s` is already a character class and doesn't need to be in square brackets. I see no reason why the trailing lookahead would be necessary in this case anyway.

Comment: `You can use the following regular expression`, and what are you doing with it?

Comment: please see edit - as per a suggestion from another user I used console.log and saw the value is &gt on page not > - As for what I'm doing with it - Ill be running a string through a removeAttribute("href"); to remove all links, what is left is replacing these >> (&gt)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do that:
You will need to invoke `replace()` with a regex that matches globally all occurrences of `>>` using the `g` modifier:

```
let newText = oldText.replace(/>>/g, "/");
```

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("#start");
let span = document.querySelector("#catidX");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  let oldText = span.innerText;
  let newText = oldText.replace(/>>/g, "/");
  span.innerText = newText;


});
```

```html
<span id="catidX"> Test 2 >> Cat >> Cat2 >> Cat4 || //// Cat /// Cat2 // Cat4 // CCat / CCat2 // CCat3 ///</span>
<br />
<button id="start">Replace</button>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ahmad but this did not address all issues and the suggestion of using 'g' modifier - you would have noticed each of the statements I tried used that. Thank you though for the thought.